# QueryLoader2 + LoadGo

Tags: javascript

I want to link the effect´s of LoadGO with QueryLoader2 , but I can not call the function of LoadGO within the QueryLoader2 . Could anyone help me solve this problem? The LoadGO Loading the effect is incredible and the mechanics of QueryLoader is perfect , so I 'm trying to combine the two codes . Follows the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/libs/font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- QUERYLOADER2 -->
    <script src="js/queryloader2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

  </head>



    <body>

  <!-- =======================================
    Preloader - QUERYLOADER2 DEPENDENCIES
  ============================================ -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
     window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

     "use strict";
        new QueryLoader2(document.querySelector("body"), {
                 barColor: "#f31e1e",
                 backgroundColor: "#fff",
                 percentage: true,
                 barHeight: 2,
                 completeAnimation: "grow",
                 minimumTime: 300,
                 fadeOutTime: 1200,
                 deepSearch: true,
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        #qLoverlay::before {
        width:600px;
        height:600px;
        position:absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        content:url(logos/tauri_3d.png); /* verificar tamanho da imagem e dividir por 2(DOIS) para alinhamento em "margin-left" */
        margin-left: -600px;
        margin-top: -750px;
    }
    </style>

    <div class="teste">
        <p align="justify">A FUNCAO TEM QUE RODAR ANTES DAQUI !!!!</p>
    </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/loadgo/loadgo.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main_loadgo.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/queryloader2.min.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>


Ahead , the main_loadgo.js function ( LoadGO )


var tauriInterval;

function execute (_id, index, interval) {
  $('#msg-' + index).animate({
    'opacity': '0'
  });

  $('#progress-' + index).animate({
    'opacity': '1'
  });

  var p = 0;
  $('#' + _id).loadgo('resetprogress');
  $('#progress-' + index).html('0%');
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    interval = window.setInterval(function (){
      if ($('#' + _id).loadgo('getprogress') == 100) {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
        $('#msg-' + index).animate({
          'opacity': '2'
        });
        $('#progress-' + index).animate({
          'opacity': '0'
        });
      }
      else {
        var prog = p*5;
        $('#' + _id).loadgo('setprogress', prog);
        $('#progress-' + index).html(prog + '%');
        p++;
      }
    }, 150);
  }, 300);
}

$(window).load(function () {

  $("#tauri").load(function() {
    // id de chamada da imagem
    $('#tauri').loadgo();
  }).each(function() {
    if(this.complete) $(this).load();
  });

});

Who can help me , thank you !
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your problem is that you are not properly using QueryLoader2 progress information to update LoadGo, so both libraries are not working together the way you did.

I had a similar experience when trying to link [Pace](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/) and LoadGo, and solve it by modifying the original Pace script. I did the following:

1. Load LoadGo script first, then pace.
2. Look where pace calculates progress value, and use it to update LoadGo progress.
3. Hide LoadGo manually when pace progress is 100%.

I think that you have to do something similar with QueryLoader2 script. Digging a little in its Github, I found the specific function where it calculates loading progress ([line 68](https://github.com/Gaya/queryloader2/blob/master/src/QueryLoader/index.js)).

So you have to download the whole code, modify that function and add LoadGo setprogress function (similar to what QueryLoader2 is doing). When you modify that file, you should run its [gulpfile](http://brandonclapp.com/what-is-gulp-js-and-why-use-it/) to concatenate and minify everything (so you will obtain a queryloader2.min.js file ready to use).

You can read a similar issue where I explain the process [here](https://github.com/franverona/loadgo/issues/8).

Happy coding! :)

PS: I'm the author of LoadGo, so feel free to ask questions and I'll try to help!